# cascade PERSIST during synchronization exception

Tags: java, eclipselink, cascade

I have a problem when trying to persist new entities. I'm using Eclipselink 2.4.2 as entity manager. My BaseDao class in the store method flushes and refreshes entity after persisting it as new (persist->flush->refresh). All is happening in a single transaction.

My entities look like this (the part I'm concerned about):

```
TrustEntity {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "trust", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @PrivateOwned
    private List<TrustIncentiveRateEntity> trustIncentiveRates;
}

TrustIncentiveRateEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRUST_ID", nullable = false)
    private TrustEntity trust;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "trustIncentiveRate", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @PrivateOwned
    private List<TrustIncentiveRateValueEntity> trustIncentiveRateValues;
}

TrustIncentiveRateValueEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_ID", nullable = false)
    private TrustIncentiveRateEntity trustIncentiveRate;
}
```

I'm creating a new Trust entity, instantiate a TrustIncentiveRateEntity list, create one new element in it, instantiate a TrustIncentiveRateEntity and create one new element in it.
During debugging I could see that all the references, in both ways, are correct.

Now, when I try to persist this here is what happens:

Log from server:

```
FINE: SELECT SEQ_TRUST.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL

FINE: SELECT SEQ_TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL

FINE: SELECT SEQ_TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_VALUE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL

FINE: INSERT INTO TRUST (TRUST_ID, ACTION_DATE, ACTION_USER_ID, IS_ACTIVE, CREATION_DATE, CREATION_USER_ID, IS_INCENTIVE_ACTIVE, IS_NO_CREDIT_LIMIT, PROCESS_CURRENT_STATUS, REMARKS, STATUS_INCENTIVE, TRUST_CODE, TRUST_NAME, TRUST_TYPE, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER_ID, VERSION_OPT_LOCK, STRUCTURAL_ORG_UNIT_SALES_ID, STRUCTURAL_ORG_UNIT_ID, USER_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [38007, 2013-04-26 09:46:31.582, 1003186, true, 2013-04-26 07:46:34.659, 1003186, true, false, OPEN, null, OPEN, 100058, 741963852, T, null, null, 1, 387, 387, 1003186]

FINE: INSERT INTO TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE (TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_ID, CREATION_DATE, CREATION_USER_ID, EQUIPMENT_SIZE, EXTENDED_EQ_GROUP_ID, RATE_BASIS, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER_ID, VERSION_OPT_LOCK, TRADE_ID, TRUST_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [15001, 2013-04-26 07:46:39.862, 1003186, 20, 2, B, null, null, 1, 144001, 38007]

FINE: INSERT INTO TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_VALUE (TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_VALUE_ID, CREATION_DATE, CREATION_USER_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, INCENTIVE, STATUS, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER_ID, VERSION_OPT_LOCK, CURRENCY_CODE, TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [14007, 2013-04-26 07:46:39.955, 1003186, 2013-04-26 00:00:00.0, 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0, 12, OPEN, null, null, 1, USD, 15001]

FINE: SELECT TRUST_ID, ACTION_DATE, ACTION_USER_ID, IS_ACTIVE, CREATION_DATE, CREATION_USER_ID, IS_INCENTIVE_ACTIVE, IS_NO_CREDIT_LIMIT, PROCESS_CURRENT_STATUS, REMARKS, STATUS_INCENTIVE, TRUST_CODE, TRUST_NAME, TRUST_TYPE, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER_ID, VERSION_OPT_LOCK, STRUCTURAL_ORG_UNIT_SALES_ID, STRUCTURAL_ORG_UNIT_ID, USER_ID FROM TRUST WHERE (TRUST_ID = ?)
    bind => [38007]

FINE: SELECT TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_ID, CREATION_DATE, CREATION_USER_ID, EQUIPMENT_SIZE, EXTENDED_EQ_GROUP_ID, RATE_BASIS, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER_ID, VERSION_OPT_LOCK, TRADE_ID, TRUST_ID FROM TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE WHERE (TRUST_ID = ?)
    bind => [38007]

FINE: SELECT TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_VALUE_ID, CREATION_DATE, CREATION_USER_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRY_DATE, INCENTIVE, STATUS, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER_ID, VERSION_OPT_LOCK, CURRENCY_CODE, TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_ID FROM TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_VALUE WHERE (TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE_ID = ?)
    bind => [15001]
```

So far so good, but when the transaction is commited by EntityManager I get the following exception:

```
WARNING: java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: my.package.entity.TrustIncentiveRateEntity@1fa1df7.
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:303)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1498)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3151)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:345)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
 at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
 at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
 at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:855)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5136)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
 at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
 at $Proxy241.save(Unknown Source)
```

Which for me seems strange, like the EM tries to actually store TrustIncentiveRateValueEntity before TrustIncentiveRateEntity and can't see TrustIncentiveRateEntity. 
After looking at similar threads I've added CascadeType.PERSIST to the @ManyToOne annotation over trustIncentiveRate field in TrustIncentiveRateValueEntity class. After that the situation looks like this: EM inserts the entities like before AND THEN it gets nextval from SEQ_TRUST_INCENTIVE_RATE and tries to insert TrustIncentiveRateValueEntity again (with the new id, but the rest of the field values remain the same). It results in constrain violation, as I have a unique constrain on cross-section of some of this table columns. Exception, transaction rolled back, I am still sad.

My store method in the BaseDao class:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
public T_ENTITY store(T_ENTITY entity) {
    if (!entity.isNewlyCreated()) {
        T_ENTITY mergedEntity = em.merge(entity);
        flush();
        return mergedEntity;
    } else {
        try {
            em.persist(entity);
            flush();
            refresh();
        } catch (RuntimeException exc) {
            entity.resetPersistentFlag();
             throw exc;
        }
        return entity;
    }
}
```

But calling the em.persist(entity) directly, without flush/refresh causes the same problem.

The logic of the service call:

```
@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public TrustEntity save(TrustEntity dto) {
    TrustEntity  trust = trustDao.store(trust);

    workflowConversation.triggerWorkflow(); // doesn't do anything to any of the entities when they are freshly created

    return trust;
}
```

Anybody could help me in identifying what could be wrong with this?

Comment: If you are getting a duplicate TrustIncentiveRateEntity when you add a cascade persist on the TrustIncentiveRateValueEntity.trustIncentiveRate relation, then it means there are two different TrustIncentiveRateEntity instances in your object tree. How are you checking they are the same in your debugging, and do you have any event or get/set methods in the entities that might change references?  For instance, if you are using property access and included business logic to set backpointers in the set method JPA must use.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a OneToMany that uses both a mappedby, making it bidirectional, and a joincolumn marking it as unidirectional.  They conflict and are causing you issues.

When you mark a relationship as mappedby, you specify that all information and control of the relationship is on the other side - that includes the joincolumn info.   try:

```
TrustEntity {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "trust", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @PrivateOwned
    private List<TrustIncentiveRateEntity> trustIncentiveRates;
}

TrustIncentiveRateEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TRUST_ID", nullable = false)
    private TrustEntity trust;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "trustIncentiveRate", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @PrivateOwned
    private List<TrustIncentiveRateValueEntity> trustIncentiveRateValues;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have already found this by myself as well, but unfortunately this doesn't fix my problem, I still get the same exception.

Comment: Fix your question then, and you will need to show more information as the problem is in one of the details you've omitted.  For instance, you mention you persist, and the log shows inserts, but then it shows selects traversing the tree.  It doesn't show how or why these selects are occurring and how they relate to the transaction - if it was just a flush, what changes are made before the transaction commits and what else is in there?  The error is not because of persisting - your log shows they are already persisted.  It is discovering an object that wasn't persisted in the tree.

Comment: I have done suggested changes to the question. 
As for the selects - I thought they were from the refresh();